# Failed to fetch file due to error "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to add install modules to a test Drupal site however I keep getting the following error:
Failed to fetch file due to error "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"
Unable to retrieve Drupal project from https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools/releases/8.x-3.4.

Things I have tried so far:

- Installing Different modules
- Downloading the latest cacert.pem file and putting it in the following folder: C:\wamp64\bin\php
- Updating the php.ini file with: curl.cainfo = "c:/wamp64/bin/php/cacert.pem"

Answer (score 2):

- download this file: [cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).
- in your php.ini, put this line:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; php.ini Options  ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

curl.cainfo = "/path/to/cacert.pem"
```

- remember, if you can't find the location of your `php.ini` file, use this command (assuming that php is installed at `/etc/php/`:

`sudo find /etc/php/ -name php.ini`

- restart your server... the problem should be solved

Comment: Hi, If you look at my original post you'll see I have already tried this and it didn't work :(

Comment: Have you checked that the file permissions on the `.pem` file are set to your user only? If windows is anything like linux, certificates and private keys need to be accessible by your user only.

Answer (score 1):

We figured it out, turns out wamp has multiple php.ini files and I was updating the wrong one >.<

For reference, it should be: C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\php.ini

Answer (score 0):

WAMP local server. **Solved!** with 3 simple steps

- Download latest cacert.pem (As txt file) from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
- Add curl.cainfo = [directory path]\cacert.pem to your php.ini
- Restart Apache service